# Flutter async and await executing not when expected

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

Method that gets data is correct, but although the getData function is marked as async and notes are from await it executes later.

The code worked like 4 days ago, but somehow now is not.
I created class FirestoreHelper with static method for getting user data based on field that I want.
Basically the only thing I changed is flutter version. After it failed I thought it may be flutter version issue and I upgraded it, but it still doesn't work.

```
class FirestoreHelper{

   static Future<dynamic> getUserDataFromDataField(String documentFieldName, String userEmail) async{
     final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final docRef = db.collection("users_data").doc(userEmail);
    docRef.get().then(
          (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print('FIRESTORE HELPER');
        print(data[documentFieldName]);
        return data[documentFieldName];
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I wanted to get data (it worked previously)

```
void getData() async{
      List<dynamic>? notes = await FirestoreHelper.getUserDataFromDataField('notes', user.email!);
      print(notes);
      if(notes == null){
        print('NO NOTES');
      } else {
        print('NOTES FOUND');
      }
}
```

The output is (in correct order):

```
null
NO NOTES
FIRESTORE HELPER
[{29, 4, 2023: ['NoteTitle', 'noteDescription']}] (correct data)
```

What can be my problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: your `FirestoreHelper.getUserDataFromDataField` method does not return anything (so `null` is implicitly returned) - simply remove that `.then` - it is a common source of problems in `async` functions

Comment: @pskink your comment absolutely helped me, thanks for saving a lot of time.